# How i can filter my data in angularJS throw links?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have

[image]

in html its looks like:

```
  <ul class="filter-ul">
                <li class="filter-li">
                    <span class="filter-title">Все бренды</span>
                    <ul class="filter-ul" ng-repeat="brand in vendors |filter:query_brand">
                        <li class="filter-li"><a href="<!--TODO filtering by links-->" class="filter-link checkable">{{ brand.name }}</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
```

One item in my Json looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "Bra by Joseline",
    "category": null,
    "price": 8370.0,
    "old_price": 8370.0,
    "vendor": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Agent Provocateur",
        "seo_name": ""
    },
    "recommended": [],
    "id": 750
}
```

i want filtering my items by "vendor.name" field and i have no idea how make it reality, its my first expirience in angularJS, sorry for noob question :)

My controller look like this:

```
 (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('beo.products.controllers')
        .controller('ProductsListController', ProductsListController);

    ProductsListController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];


    function ProductsListController($scope, $http) {

        $scope.setMainClasses('catalog-page');



        activate();


        function activate() {

             $http.get('api/v1/products/').success(function(data) {
                  $scope.products = data;
                  $scope.ProductSortLeft = '-id'; //по умолчанию фильтроваться будут по обновлению
            });
            $http.get('api/v1/categories/').success(function(data) {
                  $scope.categories = data;
            });

            $http.get('api/v1/shops/').success(function(data) {
                  $scope.shops = data;
            });

            $http.get('api/v1/vendors/').success(function(data) {
                  $scope.vendors = data;
            });
        }
    }


})();
```

I use filter columns like these:

```
    <filter></filter>


<!-- CATALOG -->
<div class="catalog-main" id="catalog">

    <div class="catalog-result-options hidden-xs">
        <div class="result-alert" id="result-show-modal">Уведомление о рапродаже</div>

        <select class="selectpicker" ng-model="ProductSortLeft">
            <option value="-price">Самые дорогие</option>
            <option value="price">Самые дешевые</option>
            <option value="click_count">Популярные</option>
            <option value="-id">Новые</option>
        </select>


    </div>

    <div class="catalog-item" ng-repeat="product in products | orderBy:ProductSortLeft">
        <div class="item-pre-title">
            Бесплатная доставка $150+
        </div>
        <div class="item-img">
            <a href="/products/{{ product.id }}/"><img ng-src="{{ product.picture[0].external_img_url }}" width="150px"
                                                       height="150px" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <a href="/products/{{ product.id }}/" class="item-title">{{ product.name }}</a>
        <div class="item-price">
            <div class="price-old">{{ product.old_price }}</div>
            <b>{{ product.price }}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="item-footer">
            <a href="#" class="item-view"></a>
            <div class="item-sales-alert">
                Получить скиду
            </div>
        </div>
    </div >
```

Comment: you can use custome filter for this.

Comment: Do you mean to *sort* (display in a different order) instead of filter? Otherwise, I can't understand your question.

Comment: i add my controller, can you help me with custom filter?

Comment: @Hulehule20 i add html where i use filters column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter on vendor.name like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.filter = "";
  $scope.brands = [{
    "name": "Bra by Joseline",
    "category": null,
    "price": 8370.0,
    "old_price": 8370.0,
    "vendor": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Agent Provocateur",
      "seo_name": ""
    },
    "recommended": [],
    "id": 750
  }, {
    "name": "Another brand",
    "category": null,
    "price": 8370.0,
    "old_price": 8370.0,
    "vendor": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Agent Bond",
      "seo_name": ""
    },
    "recommended": [],
    "id": 750
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
  <input ng-model="filter" placeholder="filter" />
   <ul class="filter-ul" ng-repeat="brand in brands | filter: {vendor: {name: filter}}">
        <li class="filter-li">{{ brand.name }}</li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I need filtering by links :(

Comment: I guess I was confused by your sentence 'i want filtering my items by "vendor.name" field '... I don't see any urls in the json, where are the links coming from?

Comment: yeah right, i want filter by vendor.name, but like here ( http://www.shopstyle.com/browse/handbags )

Comment: after tap on link, or check box i want to get my sorting items list